# How to avoid costing too long for writing data to disk

Tags: c, linux

```
    static const int MAX_BUFFER_LEN = 1024*12; //in byets
    char *bff = new char[MAX_BUFFER_LEN];
    int fileflag = O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK;

    fl = open(filename, fileflag, 0666);

    if(fl < 0)
    {
        printf("can not open file! \n");
        return -1;
    }

    do
    {

        ///begin one loop
        struct timeval bef;
        struct timeval aft;
        gettimeofday(&bef, NULL);

        write(fl, bff, MAX_BUFFER_LEN);

        gettimeofday(&aft, NULL);

        if(aft.tv_usec - bef.tv_usec > 20000) //ignore second condition
        {   
            printf(" cost too long:%d \n", aft.tv_usec - bef.tv_usec);
        }   
        //end one loop

        //sleep
        usleep(30*1000); //sleep 30ms


    }while(1);
```

When I run the program on Linux ubuntu 2.6.32-24-generic, I find that the COST TOO LONG printing shows 1~2 times in a minutes. I tried both to USB disk and hard disk.I also tried this program in arm platform .This condition also happened. I think that 3.2Mbps is too high for low speed IO device. So I reduce to 0.4Mbps.It significantly reduce the printing frequency. Is any solution to control the time cost ?
  Is write() just copying the data to kenal buffer and returning immediately or waiting fo disk IO complete? Is it possible that kenal IO buffer is full and must be waiting for flush but why only several times cost so long?

Comment: (1) When reading/writing a regular file, the O_NONBLOCK flag has no effect.  (2) How fast is your file system?  That is, what throughput does `dd if=/dev/zero of=foo bs=12k count=16k conv=fsync` report? (3) You're probably not getting any errors back from `write`, but you ought to check to be sure. (4) Is anything else running that might be preempting your program a few times a minute?

Comment: 201326592 bytes (201 MB) copied, 7.48366 s, 26.9 MB/s.The cpu loading is less than 10%. @WayneConrad

Comment: You've got plenty of I/O bandwidth; far more than the 3.2 MBps that you suspect is too high.  You are focusing on the time taken by each call to `write`.  That time will necessarily have variation, due to (among other things) contention with other processes.  Instead, worry about the overall throughput.  Is it fast enough?  Then don't worry about the time that each call to `write` is taking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't accelerate the disk, but you can do other stuff while the disk is working. You needn't wait for it to be done.

This is, however, highly non-trivial to do in C. You would need nonblocking I/O, multithreading or multiprocessing. Try googling up these keywords and how to use the different techniques (you are already using a nonblocking fd up there).

Comment: non-blocking writes aren't terribly helpful, since they *fail* if the disk isn't ready to write immediately.  Async writes, on the other hand.... `aio_write` is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Your disk I/O performance is being negatively impacted by the code around each write to measure the time (and measuring time at this granularity is going to have occasional spikes as the computer does other things).

Instead, measure the performance of the code to write the entire data - start/end times *outside* the loop (with the loop properly bounded, of course).

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling a file write which you think is going to take a lot of time, then make your process to run two threads, while one is doing the main task let the other write to disk.